# Translate CLI request into PHP cURL API request with authorisation string

Tags: php, curl

I've been going round in circles trying to get this bit of code working. The problem I am facing is that there could be any number of places where something is wrong and I'm not experienced enough with cURL and API requests to know if I've just done something simple and silly somewhere. The code below is supposed to fetch a JSON response. What I am currently getting is "false". The API developer keeps giving me a CLI sample and I don't know how to "translate" that into something I can use in PHP.

I have to hide the domain, service name and authentication details in my examples.

The string I was given:

`'https://[domain]/agw/latest/services/[service]-api/latest/api/v2/[service]-actual-prizes -vk -H "Proxy-Authorization: Basic [authstr]"'`

([authstr] is the username and password, separated by a colon and BASE64 encoded - the API dev has confirmed that my authorisation string is correct)

What I have been trying:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://[domain]/agw/latest/services/lottery-api/latest/api/v2/sportka-actual-prizes');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Proxy-Authorization: Basic '.$authstr.'"
  ,"Content-type: application/json"
));
$response   =   curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

If I understand this correctly (and I'm not sure that I do), then I'm passing the URL (without flags), saying that I don't want a header in the response (I've tried TRUE as well without any success) and then passing headers with my request that includes the authorisation.

I've tried file_get_contents with a stream_context_create header but that fails too.

Am I missing a header option or flag or something in my cURL code?

Comment: Append `--libcurl program.c` to your command line and then inspect the generated source code in `program.c` to learn how that curl command line used libcurl...

Comment: I found the problem eventually. I needed define the send method as GET.

Comment: Does not parse. Your code as shown already use GET.